# function is not working, connected with input

Tags: javascript

I have tried really everything. I don't know what to do. It is not working

```
function load() {
if(acc == "a")
var d = document.getElementById('sn');
    d.style.display='block';
var b = document.getElementById('neas');
    b.style.display='none'; 
if(acc == "n")
var d = document.getElementById('sn');
    d.style.display='none';
var b = document.getElementById('neas');
    b.style.display='block'; }
```

My head:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
day = new Date(); 
hour = day.getHours();
if (hour>=3 && hour<2)
    acc = "a";
        else { acc = "n";  } 
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function load() {
    var d = document.getElementById('sn');
    var b = document.getElementById('neas');
    if(acc == "a") {
        d.style.display='block';
        b.style.display='none'; 
    } else if(acc == "n") {
        d.style.display='none';
        b.style.display='block';
    }
}
</script>
```

My body:

```
<input type="password" maxlength="20" id="sn" style="width: 180px; height: 25px; background-image: url(bginput.gif); border:0; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; color: #0099cc; text-align: center;" value="">
<input type="text" id="neas" style="width: 180px; height: 25px; background-image: url(bginput.gif); border:0; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; color: #0099cc; text-align: center;" value="You are unable to enter." readonly>
```

Sorry guys for stupid questions, I am jus a beginner in JS.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide additional markup so that we can see what it is you're doing.

Comment: Not working means what ?

Comment: from where acc comes?

Comment: @user2451963 Please explain it well.

Comment: For starters `acc = "a"` should be `acc == "a"`, same goes for the other if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace  `if(acc = "a")`

with `if(acc == "a")`

= is assignment operator

where as `==` is an comparision operator

```
   function load() {
     var d = document.getElementById('sn');
    var b = document.getElementById('neas');

    if (acc = "a") {

        d.style.display = 'block';    
        b.style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (acc = "n") {    
        d.style.display = 'none';        
        b.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors. you seem to be missing some curly brackets and the comparison operators as well should be `==` not `=`. try:

```
function load() {

    if (acc == "a") {
        var d = document.getElementById('sn');
        d.style.display = 'block';
        var b = document.getElementById('neas');
        b.style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (acc == "n") {
        var d = document.getElementById('sn');
        d.style.display = 'none';
        var b = document.getElementById('neas');
        b.style.display = 'block';
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Also there appears to be a gap in your logic. Where does acc get its value from? Also, you can set the objects `d` and `b` **once** and then in the if statement just change their display properties like this:

```
function load() {

    var d = document.getElementById('sn');
    var b = document.getElementById('neas');

    if (acc = "a") {            
        d.style.display = 'block';            
        b.style.display = 'none';
    }    
    if (acc = "n") {    
        d.style.display = 'none';        
        b.style.display = 'block';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enclose your `if` clause in `{}`. Also use `==` instead of `=` when comparing, `=` is an assignment operator, and therefor will not pass your `if` clause.

```
 function load() {
    var d = document.getElementById('sn');
    var b = document.getElementById('neas');

    if(acc == "a"){
      d.style.display='block';
      b.style.display='none'; 
    }

    else if(acc == "n"){          
      d.style.display='none';          
      b.style.display='block';
   } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have seen the first problem by indenting : You're missing some block delimiters.

```
function load() {
    var d = document.getElementById('sn');
    var b = document.getElementById('neas');
    if (acc == "a") {
        d.style.display='block';
        b.style.display='none'; 
    } else if (acc == "n") {
        d.style.display='none';
        b.style.display='block';
    }
}
```

As seen by PSR, you also used = instead of ==.

I also changed your code to reuse the element declarations (try to be DRY) and an `else if` lets the JS engine avoid a useless test.

Comment: `acc = "a"` dystroy :) aaahaa Edited :) :)